# How to get Login successful alert to trigger only one time after signing in

Tags: php, html

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-4 small-centered columns">
            
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?> 

                <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">

                  Login successful!
                    
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></div>
                

         <?php } elseif (isset($_SESSION['login_error'])) { ?>

                <div data-alert class="alert-box alert round">

                  <?php print $_SESSION['login_error']; ?>

                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></div>
                

            <?php } ?>

      </div>
  </div>
```

When $_Session['user'] has been set I want the 'Login successful' message to appear only once after signing in. If I refresh the page or click an anchor message will reappear, which is to be expected. If anyone knows a better way of doing this or if it is possible only in php.

Comment: You probably use POST data to login users ? Just check if these variables have been sent, and if so, it means the user just logged in.

Comment: Why don't you do it in JavaScript?

Comment: you have to write this at authentication logic only not here

Comment: This is not really that helpful , maybe link me a tutorial or a thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set a observer value to see whether the value you want to be able to hide is active or not. this code should help.

```
<?PHP 
 session_start(); 

 $_SESSION['login_status']=false; 

 ?>
```

```
  <div class="small-4 small-centered columns">

      <?php if($_SESSION['login_status']==false){  ?>

              <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>

                    <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">
                        Login succesful!
                        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                    </div>

                    <?php  $_SESSION['login_status']=true;  ?>


            <?php } elseif (isset($_SESSION['login_error'])) { ?>

                  <div data-alert class="alert-box alert round">

                      <?php print $_SESSION['login_error']; ?>

                      <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                  </div>
            <?php } ?>

      <?php } ?>

  </div>
```

Comment: I went with your idea and I managed to make it worked although I changed it so that the value of $_Session['login_status'] = TRUE when the login is successful and to change it to FALSE after the notification has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

Set a second variable that shows the user has already navigated this section. You may have to add some logic as to where you send the user if beenthere is TRUE, but the general idea below solves your problem.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { 

                 if(! isset($_SESSION['beenthere') {
                 ?>
                 <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">

                  Login succesful!
                  <?php $_SESSION['beenthere'] = TRUE;?>

                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></div>
```